# Proof of "If $ZFC$ proves there is an inaccessible cardinal, then $ZFC$ is inconsistent".

Tags: logic, set-theory, incompleteness, large-cardinals

Let $I$ be the statement "there is an inaccessible cardinal".

I'm aware of two proofs of "If $ZFC\vdash I$ then $ZFC$ is inconsistent".

One proof uses the Second Incompleteness Theorem, which I understand.

The other proof goes something like:

1) Suppose $ZFC\vdash I$.

2) Then we have $ZFC\vdash ^{\backprime\backprime} V_\kappa\models ZFC ^{\prime\prime}$ where $\kappa$ is the least inaccessible cardinal.

3) Then by absoluteness results, we have $ZFC\vdash ^{\backprime\backprime}V_\kappa\models\neg I ^{\prime\prime}$.

4) Thus we have a model of $ZFC+\neg I$

And this is where this version of the proof ends in all sources I've come across.

I was wondering how the rest of the proof should go to get that $ZFC$ really is inconsistent.

My idea was it is essential to use the fact:

(*) If $ZFC\vdash\varphi$ then $ZFC\vdash ^{\backprime\backprime}ZFC\vdash\varphi ^{\prime\prime}$ for any sentence $\varphi$.

Then to finish:

5) Since we've assumed $ZFC\vdash I$, then we have $ZFC\vdash ^{\backprime\backprime}ZFC\vdash I ^{\prime\prime}$ by (*).

6) And since $ZFC\vdash ^{\backprime\backprime}V_\kappa\models ZFC^{\prime\prime}$, then we have $ZFC\vdash ^{\backprime\backprime}V_\kappa\models I ^{\prime\prime}$ by using 5).

7) By 3), we have $ZFC\vdash ^{\backprime\backprime}V_\kappa\nvDash I ^{\prime\prime}$.

8) So since $ZFC\vdash ^{\backprime\backprime}V_\kappa\models I ^{\prime\prime}$ and $ZFC\vdash ^{\backprime\backprime}V_\kappa\nvDash I ^{\prime\prime}$, then $ZFC$ is inconsistent.

Is this the way the proof is typically finished or is it somehow not necessary to appeal to (*)?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm not a set theorist, so I could be missing a lot of detial, but I think 1) and 4) contradict one another. To wit if $ZFC\vdash I$ then by the completeness theorem $M \vDash I$ for every model $M$ of ZFC. Hence there is no model of $ZFC + \neg I$, a contradiction?

Comment: @James Even your method does not avoid the basic idea of what the OP wrote. 4 is not written properly. "Thus we have a model of $ZFC + \neg I$" is not accurate since it loses track of where this proof is going on. Really it should be written $\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash "\mathsf{ZFC} + \neg I$ has a model". Afterward, by noting that $ZFC \vdash$ "Godel Completeness Theorem" and applying the Godel completeness theorem inside $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then you would the contradict you described. This is essentially the OP proof. Regardless everything is happening syntaxically in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: @ William, I know, 4) is a bit ambiguous, because it is really a theorem of $ZFC$ that that there is a model of $ZFC+\neg I$. The reason I left it that way is because that is how some sources word it (for instance Jech). I'm not sure what the motivation is behind the ambiguity. Also, @James, the authors restrict the theory to finitistic reasoning, so we must restrict our use of such model theoretic arguments in establishing the inconsistency of $ZFC$.

Comment: @William Are you also using (*) to obtain your contradiction in $ZFC$?

Comment: Essentially yes. What (*) really mean is that $\mathsf{ZFC}$  can formalize it own version of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Then you can talk about models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (like $V_\kappa$) inside $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: @William Thanks for your help. I was just trying to figure out if $(*)$ is essential to the argument since $(*)$ seems like an intuitive but nontrivial fact. If I'm not mistaken, $(*)$ follows from the fact that $ZFC$ proves any true $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence.

Comment: Sorry, in my reply above to @James I meant to write "metatheory" instead of "theory"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the argument schematically. For instance, using induction in the metatheory you could show that (1) when $\phi$ is an axiom of ZFC, ZFC proves "if $V_\kappa$ is an inaccessible rank, then $V_\kappa\vDash \phi$"; and (2) when $\psi$ is a consequence of $\phi$, ZFC proves "if $M\vDash \phi$, then $M\vDash \psi$".

Comment: Can you prove that $\sf ZFC$ proves that the object it internalizes as $\sf ZFC$ is the same object as the meta-theory's $\sf ZFC$ (in semantical terms, can you always prove that $\sf ZFC$ as perceived by the meta-universe and the universe are the same object)? Because if not, then just showing that $V_\kappa$ satisfies all the axioms we agree make "$\sf ZFC$" might not be sufficient. You need the fact that $(V_\kappa,\in)$ has a truth predicate.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, @AsafKaragila. Are you denying that (1) or (2) are provable in the metatheory, or that the argument to "ZFC is inconsistent" can't be carried out using them?

Comment: No, I stipulate that in the case that $M$ is a model of $\sf ZFC+I$ which has non-standard integers, $V_\kappa^M$ will satisfy *more* than just $\sf ZFC$, because $(\sf ZFC)^\it M\neq\sf ZFC$.

Comment: Sorry for being slow! Here's the argument I'm proposing, using (1) and (2). Suppose ZFC proves In. Then In is a consequence of some conjunction $\phi$ of finitely many axioms of ZFC. By (1) ZFC will prove that if $V_\kappa$ is the least inaccessible rank, $V_\kappa\vDash \phi$. So by (2) ZFC will prove that if $V_\kappa$ is the least inaccessible rank, $V_\kappa\vDash In$. But ZFC proves that least inaccessible rank doesn't satisfy In. So ZFC is inconsistent. Where does the argument go wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That argument is fine, but it's not quite the argument given in your answer. Your answer suggests that (1) We prove that $V_\kappa$ satisfy each individual axiom of $\sf ZFC$. In the comment you suggest to only prove that for a finite fragment sufficient for proving an inaccessible cardinal exist, and that's different.

Comment: I used quotes to mark the fact that "where $\phi$ is an axiom of ZFC" and "where $\phi$ is a consequence of $\phi$" are outside the scope of "ZFC proves". I guess that wasn't clear. I will edit.

Comment: @GME Thanks for your response. I like the schematic argument, but I'm curious if the justification for your (2) avoids using my $(*)$ or something very similar. I know that my $(*)$ follows from the fact that $ZFC$ proves any true $\Sigma^{0}_1$ sentence. So to clarify: Does your (2) essentially just follow from induction in the metatheory, and then a little bit of model theory carried out inside $ZFC$? Thanks

Comment: That's right. For instance, we note that ZFC proves $M\vDash \phi \to (M\vDash \psi \to M\vDash \phi)$ and then, using a bit of (very simple!) model theory in ZFC, that ZFC proves $M\vDash \phi \to (\psi \to \phi)$. Similarly for the other logical axioms and rules of inference. So (2) is proved using just basic model theory in ZFC.

Comment: There is an interesting method you can use here. Suppose $M$ is a model of ZFC in which $\kappa$ is inaccessible. Recall NBG is finitely axiomatized. Then $M$ will satisfy "$V_{\kappa + 1}$ is a model of NBG". Then, by formalizing the usual proof of "NBG $\to$ ZFC" inside ZFC, we have that $M$ satisfies "$V_\kappa$ satisfies ZFC" where the latter quantifies *internally* over all the axiom schemes of ZFC.

Comment: @CarlMummert Nice. So we could replace my (1) and (2) with: (1') ZFC proves "if $V_\kappa$ is an inaccessible rank, then $V_\kappa\vDash NBG$; and (2') when $\psi$ is a second-order (proof-theoretic) consequence of $\phi$, ZFC proves "if $M\vDash \phi$, then $M\vDash \psi$" (where the second-order quantifiers in $\phi$ and $\psi$ range over subsets of $V_\kappa$ and $M$).